# Time-Based Workflow Not Working In Production

Tags: administration, time-dependent-workflow

I created a time-based workflow to send email notifications and task. It is working as designed in Sandboxes but when I deployed it into Production using change sets and it will not work in Production.

I have compared all criteria regarding the Workflow rule side-by-side with Sandbox and Production and it is identical. No change was made to it and all the related components exist in Prod as they do in Sandbox.

I couldn't find a solution for it. Any help would be great!

**WORKFLOW RULE**

[image]

**TASK**

[image]

**EMAIL ALERT**

[image]

Comment: Not working how? Please edit your question and provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: not to mention how does your workflow criteria get met in production? It doesn't evaluate records on its own, it only evaluates records when they're created/updated. Is something updating `PreReqs Rec'd`? Otherwise, this could just be a testing issue where you're purposefully updating the date to `today` so it meets criteria. In production, presumably that date is set way in advance so it would never `= today` unless someone updates the date or other field on that exact date.

Comment: @identigral It is not triggering the email alerts or task to be created. It is only happening in Prod. Working just fine in SBX. Basically nothing is triggering in Prod in that workflow rule.

Comment: @identigral PreReqs Rec'd is a checkbox field. PreReqs Due Date is a date field. When PreReq Due date = TODAY and PreReqs Rec'd checkbox = FALSE, it should trigger those alerts to the involved parties (Project manager and Client Success Manager).

Answer (score 1):

Time-Based Workflow Rules only work on records that were modified and met the criteria after deploy deploying the workflow rule and activating it. To verify this, try creating a new record that meets the criteria, then head over the Time-Based Workflow and verify that an entry has appeared there. You will need to modify existing records (e.g. with the Apex Data Loader) to queue up those records.